# Image no longer displays when adding 'id' attribute to image tag

Tags: php, html

I have a grid of images that is generated on a page with PHP. This is the HTML for each image:

```
Echo "<img src= '$link[Image_Link] . /133x100' title='$row[Item_Name]' alt='$just_name' onClick='addValue(". $credit_value .")' border=0 style='position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;'/>"
```

This is with the ID:

```
Echo "<id='img1' img src= '$link[Image_Link] . /133x100' title='$row[Item_Name]' alt='$just_name' onClick='addValue(". $credit_value .")' border=0 style='position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;'/>"
```

The `src`, `title`, `alt`, etc attributes are being correctly set.

If I try to add any kind of `id`, for example: `<id="img" src=....` it seems to break the HTML code and the image will no longer appear.

Why is this happening? I need the images to have an id so I can use them with jquery functions.

Comment: could you show us which code is produced in HTML here?

Comment: I'm a bit confused? Are you Echo / printing this line? What's the output?

Comment: What do each of those variables produce? Where are you trying to add the `id` attribute? I suspect that you've got stray quotes in at least one of the variables, though why that 'only' (allegedly) causes trouble when you add an `id` I don't know.

Comment: @vihan1086 's question needs an answer.  It looks like you are using echo since you are printing $credit_value, but would be easier if you posted more of what you are doing.

Comment: I just edited my question, sorry it didn't have enough info.

Comment: The element's tag-name ***must be*** the *first* string (with not even a white-space) after the `<` character. So yes, `<id='img'` is entirely wrong and *will* break your HTML. [Simple demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rywh26s4/).

Comment: It means the tagname of an HTML element is the first thing inside of an HTML tag: `<img />`, `<div />`, etc; anything that comes between the tagName ('img', 'div', etc) and the '<' character breaks your HTML because it's invalid and the browser doesn't know what the hell it should be attempting with that morass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```html
<div id="myId">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" id="myImgId">
</div>
```

Comment: While I don't need the <div>, my id was in the wrong spot, so this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This code is wrong:

```
<id='img1' img src=....
```

It should look like this:

```
<img id="img1" src= .../>
```

Comment: Not if each image is unique and you need to use jquery functions on individual ones.

Comment: While your comments regarding the use of a class-name versus `id` are pointless and entirely incidental, you're absolutely right that it "*should look like... `<img src="..." />`*".

Comment: @user1795832 The tag is the problem, not the attribute, as indicated. `<id>` is not a valid tag; `<img>` is. Attributes _always_ follow the tag text, never precede it.

Comment: Yes that is correct, this question has been modified a few times.